# Query on the 'namelist.input' file for running WRF-Chem to study aerosol-cloud-climate interaction

Tags: meteorology, numerical-modelling, wrf-chem, aerosol, cloud-microphysics

I have a small inquiry about the setup of some variables in 'namelist.input' file for running WRF-Chem to study aerosol-cloud-climate interaction. After going through various research papers on aerosol-cloud interaction studies using the WRF-Chem model, the user guides, and tutorial presentations available on the WRF-Chem official webpage, I noticed that the cumulus parameterization scheme is not used if the resolution of the domain is 4 km or less than 4 km. Then, if I set the resolution of my d02 as 4 km, should the options "cu_physics" be set to "0" and "cu_rad_feedback" be set to "false" for that domain?

I also learned that to study the aerosol indirect effect, the options "wetscav_onoff" and "cldchem_onoff" should be set to 1. And it is mentioned in the "Best Practices for Applying WRF-Chem 3.9.1.1" tutorial presentation that in the "chem" section of the namelist, "conv_tr_aqchem" and "conv_tr_wetscav" should be set to 1 to include aqueous chemistry and convective wet scavenging. So, what should I set for the options "chem_conv_tr", "conv_tr_wetscav", and "conv_tr_aqchem" for d02 (4 km)? "0" or "1"'? Could someone please help me sort this out? It will be very helpful for me. Thank you for your time and consideration.
With regards,
Ankan